# Load-balancing PostgreSQL queries using two different Spring datasources

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, replication

We're attempting to set up a PostgreSQL cluster using streaming replication inside Kubernetes, but we'd prefer to avoid the trouble of going through the configuration of `pgpool` or any other SQL-aware load-balancers.

That being said, I'd like to ask whether it is a good idea at all to configure Spring Boot to use two datasources in the following way:

- The first (`@Primary`) datasource would point towards the current PostgreSQL master and be used for read and write operations.
- The second datasource would point towards a hot-standby replica and be used for read operations.

Provided that there are Kubernetes services that point to the current master and to the read replicas, and that failover is *not* automated, are there any risks in this approach?

Comment: we are also going for the exactly same architecture. But after coming across pgPool we thought to give it a try. But the difficult setup & configuration of PgPool is delaying our project.

But still we are thinking of going with pgPool way only.